# Where do I find a firmware/driver for the "Freenet TV" DVB-T2 USB stick?

Tags: firmware, tv, dvb-t

I recently switched my parent's laptop from Windows to Ubuntu 20.04. They use an USB dongle marketed by "Freenet TV" to watch German terrestrial TV when on holidays. This stick seems not to be working out of the box, at least in Kaffeine. From what I found on the Internet so far, I guess that I need some firmware to make it work, but I have no clue where to find it. Some others had the same problem back in 2017: https://forum.ubuntuusers.de/topic/dvb-t2-mit-freenet-stick/

This is the respective device as output by `lsusb`:

```
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 29df:0280 SMiT USBDONGLE
```

And this is the output of `dmesg` when plugging the stick in:

```
[ 3277.295945] usb 2-2: new high-speed USB device number 5 using ehci-pci
[ 3277.453981] usb 2-2: New USB device found, idVendor=29df, idProduct=0280, bcdDevice= 1.00
[ 3277.453987] usb 2-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 3277.453991] usb 2-2: Product: USBDONGLE
[ 3277.453994] usb 2-2: Manufacturer: SMiT
[ 3277.453997] usb 2-2: SerialNumber: 1702032860
```

This is the output of `usb-devices | awk '/29df/' RS=`:

```
T:  Bus=02 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=01 Cnt=01 Dev#=  6 Spd=480 MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=ef(misc ) Sub=02 Prot=01 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=29df ProdID=0280 Rev=01.00
S:  Manufacturer=SMiT
S:  Product=USBDONGLE
S:  SerialNumber=1702032860
C:  #Ifs= 2 Cfg#= 1 Atr=80 MxPwr=500mA
I:  If#=0x0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=11 Prot=01 Driver=(none)
I:  If#=0x1 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=11 Prot=02 Driver=(none)
```

Where can I find the respective firmware? Is there some repository or list for firmwares? Or is there some other solution to make it work? If there is none, how hard would it be to program one based on some sample?

Comment: Please [edit] the question and add output of `usb-devices | awk '/29df/' RS=` command.

Comment: Please keep in mind that if there is software on it to enable watching TV it is likely encrypted and protected (ie. DRM) from being used on anything else than Windows. A driver is not going to fix this. One method to get it working would be through virtual box and installing windows into that.

Comment: it is not listed here: https://linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/DVB-T_USB_Devices + 5 year old topic:  https://tvheadend.org/boards/5/topics/25554

Comment: I would start by installing v4l (video4linux). It will pull in some devices drivers. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video4Linux Maybe also freenet :)

Comment: The device is not supported. It is unclear what chip is used. So it wouldn't be easy to get it working on Linux. The firmware can be found in a Windows driver, but a driver is still needed.

Comment: That sounds like bad news, but thanks anyway. @Rinzwind: Installing v4l didn't help. And regarding encryption, the public TV stations (ARD, ZDF, ...) would suffice, which I would hope to be unencrypted.

Comment: yeah, you will need virtualbox+windows or a dualboot to use it :(